# Are both "inherits" and "classname" required?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have inherited someone elses code and was wondering if there is any reason I would need to keep both of these in the page directives? I have tried it removing classname and things still seem to work. Just wondering.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="YourProgram.ascx.cs" Inherits="program.YourProgram" ClassName="program.YourProgram" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ascx file doesn't contain any code, the `ClassName` attribute is not needed, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thirusrinivasan/archive/2008/07/16/classname-vs-inherits.aspx.

However, `Inherits` and `ClassName` do different things. `ClassName` will set the name of the class generated out of the ascx file, while `Inherit` will make the generated class inherit from the class in the code behind:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d19c0t4b(v=vs.100).aspx